# Are all constants of integration $C$ equal?

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals, constants

This is a question from very (very) basic calculus, but it concerns indefinite integrals and the constant $ C $ we always add when we find the antiderivative. This concerns some problems with subtracting two indefinite integrals.

Say we have $ f(\theta) = \sin(\theta) $

And we have $ h(\theta) = \cos(\theta) $

(These are simple examples to illustrate the point.)

Now, $ \int \sin(\theta) d\theta = -\cos(\theta) + C $
And $ \int \cos(\theta) d\theta = \sin(\theta) + C $

This is the question:

Is $ (\int f(x) dx) - F(x) = (\int g(x) dx) - G(x) $?

Here, the capital letters represent the antiderivatives where $C = 0$.

Edit: This is a *stupid* question I posted in the very beginning before I even knew how to do things on MSE. Please take this question with a grain of salt. My real questions start on the (sadly) deleted account @AbysmalMathematics.

Comment: so basically are you asking if the two constant of integration are the same?

Comment: "Here, the capital letters represent the antiderivatives without the constant of integration." - There is **no such thing** as "the antiderivative without the constant of integration". The functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ have infinitely many antiderivatives. You have to choose particular ones to be $F(x)$ and $G(x)$. Which ones are you choosing? $\int f(x)dx$ does not refer to some single antiderivative, but to the entire family of anti-derivatives, so you will also need to define what you even mean by $\int f(x)dx - F(x)$. It is not a number.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I suggest you read the edit. What I really mean is that “without the constant” refers to $C = 0$.

Comment: You missed my point. Saying $C = 0$ is *meaningless* without specifying the specific  antiderivative to which you are adding "$C$" to get the whole family. There is not a unique $F$ or unique $G$ that would make your equation fully defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question is definitely "No". Here is an example.
I can write $\int 2 \sin x \cos x dx = \sin^2 x + C$. This means "any function whose derivative is $2 \sin x \cos x$ is equal to $\sin^2 x$ plus some constant". Also, however, $\int 2 \sin x \cos x dx = -\cos^2 x + C'$. If we treat $\int 2 \sin x \cos x dx$ as a well defined function, we can deduce $\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x = C' - C$; that is, $\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x$ is equal to an arbitrary constant, which it isn't. It's even worse if we "choose" $C=C'$, because $\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x \neq 0$. How we should interpret the pair of integrals is "any function whose derivative is $2 \sin x \cos x$ is equal to $\sin^2 x$ plus some constant and also equal to $-\cos^2 x$ plus some other constant", from which we can deduce that $\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x$ is constant, which is fine, because it is.

Answer (score -3):

Conventionally, if F is the antiderivative of f, then $F(x)=\int _0 ^x f(t)dt=\int f(x)dx+C$ with $C=0$. Therefore, $\int f(x)dx-F(x)=C$ where C is the constant of integration of $\int f(t)dt$ that one can set as equal to any wanted (constant) value in $\mathbb{R}$.
In your situation, $\int f(t)dt -F(x)=\int g(t)dt -G(x)$ iff you choose the same constant of integration for $\int f(t)dt$ and for $\int g(t)dt$.
Hope this is clear enough !

Comment: I don't agree with this answer. The problem is that you are treating $\int f(x) dx$ as a well defined object, when it isn't. When you write $\int f(x) dx = F(x) +C$, what you are saying is "any of the functions whose derivative is $f(x)$ can be written as a specific function which you have chosen whose derivative is $f(x)$ + a constant". You can't then say, for instance, "when I've chosen $C=0$, $\int f(x) dx = F(x)$, because the left-hand side still means "any of the functions ..." and they aren't all equal to $F(x)$. Thus the result must be $\int f(x) dx - F(x) = \int g(x) dx - G(x) + C$.

Comment: Yes I agree, my answer was (at least) not clear enough. Actually, I just wanted to point out that as soon as one is only looking at antiderivatives (and therefore is only concerned of the derivative)  of a given function, the integration constant C can be chosen arbritraly.  Also, I wanted to add a comment, not answer but I was not able to as I don't have enough reputation.